# Dynamic `ng-model` in `ng-repeat` for multilingual inputs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, multilingual

In my current multilingual Angularjs app, I have some inputs that have multiple values in each languages(*en, fa, ar* and ...) like this:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="lang in languages">
   <label> {{'TITLE' | translate}}</label>
   <input class='form-control'
       type='text'
       name="title"
       ng-model="createModel.lang['title']">
</div>

<div ng-repeat="lang in languages">
   <label> {{'NAME' | translate}}</label>
   <input class='form-control'
       type='text'
       name="name"
       ng-model="createModel.lang['name']">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$rootScope.languages  = ['en', 'fa', 'ar']; // array of languages
```

Means that, I want to have `ng-model` like these:

```
en: 
  ng-model='createModel.en["title"]'
  ng-model='createModel.en["name"]'
fa: 
  ng-model='createModel.fa["title"]'
  ng-model='createModel.fa["name"]'
ar: 
  ng-model='createModel.ar["title"]'
  ng-model='createModel.ar["name"]'
```

At last I want this for `createModel`:

```
createModel: {
    'en': ['title': 'title1' , 'name': 'Jone'],
    'fa': ['title': 'عنوان1' , 'name': 'جان'],
    'ar': ['title': '...' , 'name': '...']
}
```

**So, How can I do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
createModel.lang['title']
```

to

```
createModel[lang].title
```

(and same for the name, obviously).

Also note that your JS code is invalid. It should be

```
createModel: {
  'en': {'title': 'title1' , 'name': 'Jone'},
  'fa': {'title': 'عنوان1' , 'name': 'جان'},
  'ar': {'title': '...' , 'name': '...'}
}
```

An array starts with `[`. An object starts with `{`.

Comment: I want to (fa, en, ar and...) be an array not an object

Comment: No, you don't. An array contains indexed values ['a', 'b', 'c'] where 'a' is array[0]. You want key value pairs, and that's what an object is for. Why would you store key value pairs in an array? That would only make things extremely confusing. And you're already cofused, so...

Comment: In restful API, My teammate needs: `en: ['title'='...', 'name'='...']`. for this reason I want to create this model(array)

Comment: No, he doesn't. Arrays containing key value pairs don't even exist in JSON. If the backend API expects a bizarre format that is not JSON, then use a proper, readable, intuitive JavaScript data structure, and transform this JavaScript data structure to this bizarre data format when sending the data to the API.

Comment: OK I got it, Thanks a lot :)